# error: The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code and the part of data in ultimate is also provided as you can see. When I run this code in vs code in my computer I get this error:

```
 ultimate = np.array(ultimate)   
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (81, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

However, when. I run this code on another computer. It doesn't show any error and it runs totally correct. Can anyone suggest me what's wrong with my code?

```
for q in nonoutliersPos:
                ultimate.append(cluster0Data[q])
          print('ultimate:',ultimate)      
          ultimate = np.array(ultimate) 



ultimate:
[(array([3.72660978e+08, 4.16826783e+00, 6.76000000e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00]), 199), (array([3.72660954e+08, 4.16826783e+00, 6.76000000e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00]), 201), (array([3.72660978e+08, 4.16826783e+00, 6.76000000e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00]), 202), (array([3.72660954e+08, 4.16826783e+00, 6.76000000e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00]), 203), (array([ 2.63184231e+08,  4.16799028e+00, -7.13000000e-05, -4.55000000e-13,
        0.00000000e+00]), 211), (array([ 2.63184237e+08,  4.16799028e+00, -7.13000000e-05, -4.55000000e-13,
        0.00000000e+00]), 212)]
```

I wrote pip list in command line. Here is the answer:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ------------
contourpy       1.2.0
cycler          0.12.1
et-xmlfile      1.1.0
fonttools       4.44.3
joblib          1.3.2
kiwisolver      1.4.5
matplotlib      3.8.2
networkx        3.2.1
numpy           1.24.3
openpyxl        3.1.2
packaging       23.2
pandas          2.0.3
Pillow          10.1.0
pip             22.3.1
plotly          5.18.0
pyparsing       3.1.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3.post1
ruptures        1.1.8
scikit-fuzzy    0.4.2
scikit-learn    1.3.2
scipy           1.11.4
setuptools      65.5.0
six             1.16.0
tenacity        8.2.3
threadpoolctl   3.2.0
tzdata          2023.3
```

Comment: Could you give us some more information about the two different computers, such as their operating system, python and numpy version... ?

Comment: `ultimate` is a list of tuples. Each tuple contains an array and an number.  That cannot be made into a numeric dtype array.  Older numpy versions might have made an object dtype array.

Comment: On the computer where it runs, what's the resulting array's `shape` and `dtype`?

Answer (score 1):

Degrade your numpy

e.g.
`pip install numpy==1.23.0`

Comment: So is this a known bug in NumPy, and will it be fixed in future versions? Some context for this answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct :) It's a version problem. You should downgrade to an older version of numpy.

[This is](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#history) the page for all versions of numpy. You must install the one dated *June 23, 2022*, therefore version `1.23.0`. [Here is](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.23.0/) the version 1.23.0 page.

Uninstall your numpy first (you may not need to, but better to uninstall anyway)

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

Then install it with:

```
pip install numpy==1.23.0
```

P.S: If that doesn't work, then install `1.22.4` dated *May 20, 2022*, using the same method